# conversion of subject name into x509_name format

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509certificate, x509

I have subject name of CA certificate in `CN=CA1, O=DEVANG`.
I want to convert into `X509_NAME` format.

Is there any APIs to help me convert it ?
How can I compare ?

Comment: Did the answer below address your question?

Answer (score 1):

There do not seem to be any helper functions available in OpenSSL to do this. It looks like the only way to achieve what you want is by parsing the string and building up the `X509_NAME_ENTRY` elements one by one. You could use `strsep` for that, resulting in something like this code (which does not do any error checking and is error prone with regard to variations in the name format):

```
#define TEST_NAME "CN=CA1, O=DEVANG"

X509_NAME *x509name = X509_NAME_new();
char *x509nameString = strdup(TEST_NAME);
char *toFree = x509nameString;
char *x509nameEntryString = strsep(&x509nameString, ",");
char *x509nameEntryTypeString;
char *x509nameEntryValueString;

while (NULL != x509nameEntryString) {
  x509nameEntryValueString = x509nameEntryString;
  x509nameEntryTypeString = strsep(&x509nameEntryValueString, "=");
  X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(x509name, x509nameEntryTypeString,
      MBSTRING_ASC, x509nameEntryValueString, -1, -1, 0);
  /* Need to skip spaces */
  while ((NULL != x509nameString) &&
         (' ' == *x509nameString)) {
    x509nameString = &x509nameString[1];
  }
  x509nameEntryString = strsep(&x509nameString, ",");
}

/* See the result, just FYI */
X509_NAME_print_ex_fp(stdout, x509name, 0, XN_FLAG_ONELINE);

free(toFree);
```

For comparing two `X509_NAME` instances, the function `X509_NAME_cmp()` is available.

I do hope somebody has a better answer...